# Why does overflow break translateZ positioning?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-transforms

I'm working on a parallax effect and would like to align my layer in 3D space using translateZ. But adding an overflow property to the wrapper seems to break the Z-positioning of its children. You can try it out in [this](https://codepen.io/Fabian86/pen/BaJvqVw) Codepen by simply deleting line 6 in the CSS. As soon as the overflow is gone, the #back div correctly displays in front of the #front div, due to its bigger Z value.

Any idea why this happens and how I can fix this behaviour?

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 90vh;
  perspective: 100px;
  perspective-origin: top left;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  overflow: hidden; /*<-- delete this line */
}

#back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 20px);
}

#front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translate3d(30px, 30px, 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="back">back</div>
  <div id="front">front</div>
</div>
```